# Basic Probability Question about number selected at random intervals with a modulus

Tags: probability

This is my thought process on solving this question, but the answer sheet is not available and I am unsure about my thought process. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Question: A number x is selected at random in the interval $[-1,2]$. Let the event $B = \{|x-0.5|<0.5\}$. Find the probability of B.

Thought process:

$B = |x-0.5|<0.5$ could be equal to

$B= x-0.5<0.5 \to B= x<1$

or

$B= x-0.5>-0.5 \to x>0$

Therefore I need to include the 2 options and its an 'OR' which means a Union.
My Answer: $P(B) = 1/3 + 2/3 = 1$

Answer (score 1):

The inequalities given inequalities say that $x\gt 0$ **and** $x\lt 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$|x-0.5|<0.5$ $\Rightarrow$ $0<x<1$ which has a length $1$. But the space has a length of $|2-(-1)|=3$.

Therefore $P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$